# How to check if a Product is installed from launch condition of msi?

Tags: msi, windows-installer

We are creating an msi, which is a sidecar/config for our main product ,an installshied exe(embedded an msi inside).

This new msi should be installed only when the main msi is already installed on the machine and also above a specific version only.

How to set that in the Launch condition of msi?
If not launch conditon, any other options in Installshield/msi.

Also, this is not for silent installation or deployment, we will provide it directly to end users to download from the product website. So we need to show a GUI based error to the user.

When I searched for launch conditions, I wasn't able to find much related to this.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have checks for certain conditions, i.e. registry or file exists.

Here is some documentation on condition types:

https://docs.revenera.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/SteConditionCheckTypes.htm#BuildingConditionalStatements_547774590_1033839

https://docs.revenera.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/SteConMSI.htm

Comment: THanks @AutoGnome but this is for Installshield Advanced UI project, But my project is basic msi project type. This feature is not available to my project file